# Is the Lennard-Jones system in Newtonian mechanics ergodic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, computational-physics

A large part of the computational physics literature relies on solving Newtons equations for deriving phase diagrams and related properties of the LJ system.

In many cases this approach does not require justification since one could be interested only in the dynamics of the system during a short time. But this is not the case if one is interested in caculating partition functions.

So I have not found any established result to ensure that this approach is sufficient for sampling the phase space and calculating partition functions.

Comment: This is certainly an open problem. And even in the simpler cases in which this type of results have been obtained, the estimates are not quantitative enough to *"ensure that this approach is sufficient for sampling the phase space and calculating partition functions"* in any realistic situation.